# PayPal Sandbox Test Account

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I created a PayPal sandbox account and tried to test my 'Pay with PayPal' button from my website (localhost) but got this error message 'error 14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure'.

I am having trouble understanding this error and how to fix it. This is my first time with PayPal.

Can somebody help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is trying to communicate with the PayPal servers using SSL version 3 which has been disabled due to the [POODLE vulnerability](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-290A). Please check with your server administrator/web host to disable SSLv3 and use the more secure and supported TLS 1.2.